# Create tooltip using Mootools

Tags: mootools, tooltip

How to create a Mootools tooltip information while focus on a text feild like http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/#form-tooltips

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made very minor adjustments to an old script by Ryan J.Salva corresponding to your request:

http://jsfiddle.net/ghazal/K7uaQ/

PS : changes commented and only for mootools 1.4.2 with compatibility. Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 2):

You may find this useful:

http://mootools.net/forge/p/floatingtips

It's a plugin I developed some time ago. You can see a demo using it for text fields focus here:

http://jsfiddle.net/X37C9/

It works with Mootools 1.4 and 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to achieve something like this.

The simplest would be to create a hidden element after the field, once you focus a field, fetch the element with the tooltip, and animate the position and opacity with `Fx.Morph`. On blur do the opposite.

Another way would be to create a single element at the bottom of the page, then fetch the position of each field with `getCoordinates`, adjust the position of the tooltip, inject the tooltip text from, say a `data-tooltip` property of the input, animate it to appear.

Using JsFiddle to prototype a solution would be the easiest.

Comment: I would like to show the title attribute as tool tip without a hidden element

Comment: Just generate an element on-the-fly. The rest of my suggestions still apply.